# "Arguments to the topic" or "arguments for the topic"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, prepositions, collocation

I'm not sure whether it is possible to say "arguments for the topic" or "arguments to the topic" when I want to express opinions that would relate to the given topic.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say either.

Arguing *for* a topic suggests that you are in favour of a topic, which doesn't seem to be your intention.

Arguing *to* a topic suggests you are directing an argument towards a topic, implying that it can hear you.

I would say either:

```
Arguments *about* a topic,
```

or

```
Arguments *relating to* a topic
```